# How to edit build.gradle for required OS platform in React native created with expo?

Tags: javascript, react-native, native

I created a React Native project with Expo. I am able to locate `build.gradle` file in created project. I need to add some configurations for the module installed. How can I solve this in another appropriate way?

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

when using expo-managed workflow you can't access native platform code (Objective-C or Java) unless you eject using `expo eject` [command](https://docs.expo.io/expokit/eject/)